# Set thickness for frame, axes, plot globally

Tags: plotting

I have many `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` in my notebook.

I each command I have added `PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick, FrameStyle -> Thick`.

How can I set these styles globally for all plots?

Comment: You could make a plot theme...

Comment: @J. M. Could you please show an example how I can define and then use such a theme.

Comment: J. M. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set it as :

```
plotset = {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
   FrameStyle -> Thick};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Evaluate@plotset]

ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Evaluate@plotset]
```

Answer (score 4):

Also possible `SetOptions[{Plot, ListPlot}, {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick, FrameStyle -> Thick}]`

Comment: This works for `Plot` but needs to be called again `ListPlot`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: combined: `SetOptions[{Plot,ListPlot}, {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick, FrameStyle -> Thick}]`

Comment: @lio I added that to the answer. Thanks.